# Are there any supplements for Sengoku?

Tags: sengoku

In planning out a new game, I stumbled over [Sengoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sengoku_(role-playing_game)) by Gold Rush Games. Presenting a very historically accurate baseline with the options to play any facette of feudal Japanese society and adding magic, monsters and anime playstyle depending on the player's wishes intrigued me.

However, I only could find the core rules have been made in 1999, that there is a revised edition of 2002 and that one of the authors - [Anthony J Bryant](http://sengokudaimyo.com/), a researcher of Japanese feudal topics - passed away.

Did any supplements for Sengoku ever made it to print?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes!

There were a few:

- **Shiki** is an adventure taking years, following your lord from youngster to adult. As adventures go, it is okay and very suitable as an introduction to the style. ISBN 1-890305-19-7. You can find an overprice copy on [amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Shiki-Epic-Adventure-Anthology-Sengoku/dp/1890305197/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1500973998&sr=8-1&keywords=1890305197). *Note that at the price of this writing (£74.95!!!), it is **not** worth it!* The original price was $16.00. I would not lose sleep over this, shiki was okay, nothing amazing.
- **Shinobi, Shadows of Nihon** and **Shinobi Ryu** are all about ninja. Both those are incredibly well researched using history over urban myths. Those are a superb addition to anyone wanting to actually learn about shinobi. The references alone are worth it!
- **Sengoku Character Sheets** is a tiny supplements with nice character sheets. I cannot comment on this one as I do not own it.

[You can (and should) get them here in pdf form…](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/browse.php?keywords=sengoku&manufacturers_id=495&x=0&y=0&author=&artist=&pfrom=&pto=).

As a side note, Sengoku is probably the best games dealing with the warring state period of Japan history. It is chock full of accurate historical research. While the system is meh, you can easily ignore it and run it with whatever your favourite is.

The [$5.99 bundle](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/29421/Sengoku-Revised-Ed-BUNDLE?manufacturers_id=495&it=1) will have it all but Shiki. At that price, I strongly encourage anyone reading this to pick it up. I would (and did) pay at least ten times that price and it was worth every penny!

---

<sup>I am neither associated with Goldrush games (although I was involved in both the alpha and beta for Sengoku) nor am I associated with drivethrurpg.</sup>

Comment: Just when I stumbled over some stuff on their old website! Great addition maybe? https://web.archive.org/web/20061126081351/http://www.sengoku.com:80/support.html

Comment: Hmmm... Legends of Sekigahara never seem to have made it to print... :(

Comment: @Trish I think Gold Rush Games folded in the early 2000s due to not enough sales of their games. They tried a few extra settings but it was not enough to rescue the company. To be honest, looking at any chambara films can give you countless plots: [The Twilight Samurai](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0351817/) would be fine example of such.

Comment: I like the Kurosawa films.